# Reading Null DateTime column from a Table in SqlServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I am having an issue reading Calls from my Call Table. One of my columns is a DateTime column, and this column I have allowed to be null, if the call has not been closed. When I execute my C# code that is to fetch all calls from the Calls table, I get an error that the data is null, cannot read when no data is present. I thought If I had an If statement that checks if that column is null, that would solve the issue... but that doesn't work.

Here is the code where I am experiencing the problem:

```
public void GetAllCalls(Connection connectionObject)
    {
        try
        {
            if (memoryObject.GetCallCount() != 0)
            {
                memoryObject.DeleteAllCalls();
            }

            SqlCommand getCalls = new SqlCommand("sp_getAllCalls", connectionObject.getDatabaseConnection());
            getCalls.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            dataReader = getCalls.ExecuteReader();
            if (dataReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    if (dataReader.GetDateTime(8).Equals(DBNull.Value))
                    {
                        Call newCall = new Call(dataReader.GetString(0), dataReader.GetString(1), dataReader.GetString(2),
                        dataReader.GetString(3), dataReader.GetString(4), dataReader.GetString(5),
                        dataReader.GetString(6), dataReader.GetDateTime(7), Convert.ToDateTime(null),
                        dataReader.GetString(9), dataReader.GetString(10), dataReader.GetString(11),
                        dataReader.GetString(12));
                        memoryObject.AddCall(newCall);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Call newCall = new Call(dataReader.GetString(0), dataReader.GetString(1), dataReader.GetString(2),
                        dataReader.GetString(3), dataReader.GetString(4), dataReader.GetString(5),
                        dataReader.GetString(6), dataReader.GetDateTime(7), dataReader.GetDateTime(8),
                        dataReader.GetString(9), dataReader.GetString(10), dataReader.GetString(11),
                        dataReader.GetString(12));
                        memoryObject.AddCall(newCall);
                    }

                }
                dataReader.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                dataReader.Close();
                functionsObject.displayMessage("No Calls Found", "No calls were found on the system");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            logNewError(error, "GetAllCalls", connectionObject);
        }

    }
```

Comment: At what line is the exception getting thrown?

Comment: The exception happens at my if statement which checks if the DateTime column has data.

Comment: And what is the exception?

Comment: The System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException is thrown with the message "Data is null. This method or property cannot be called on null values"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of checking that is using the [SqlDataReader.IsDBNull method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (dataReader.IsDBNull(8))
```